# Задача про Козла и площадь огорода. C++

Tags: c++, математика, геометрия, олимпиада

Есть такая задача, условие ниже. Написал свой код - решение в 3 из 10 тестов неверное, формула вроде правильная, на тестовом условии тоже ответ верный. Где ошибка и как исправить?  *Скорее всего ошибка в формуле, я думаю*

[image: Условие]

Мой код :

```
#include <cmath>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;
int main() {

    ifstream inp;
    ofstream otp;
    inp.open("input.txt");
    otp.open("output.txt");

    const double pi = acos(-1);

    double r = 0, l = 0, S = 0, a = 0;

    inp >> l >> r;

    S = pi * r * r;

    if (l <= 2 * r) {
        a = acos(l / 2 / r);
        S -= 4 * (a * r * r - l / 2 * r * sin(a));
    }

    otp << fixed << setprecision(6) << S;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как вариант - чтоб без синусов арккосинусов :)

```
double a, r, pi = 3.1415926;
cin >> a >> r;
cout << setprecision(7);
if (2*r <= a) cout << pi*r*r;
else if (r >= a/sqrt(2.0)) cout << a*a;
else cout << pi*r*r*(1-4*acos(a/2/r)/pi)+2*a*sqrt(r*r-a*a/4);
cout << endl;
```

Comment: Можете пожалуйста объяснить откуда берётся 3я формула? Или ссылку дать, очень нужно!

Comment: Ответьте пожалуйста.

Comment: Первая часть - площадь секторов, которые полностью внутри квадрата, а вторая - площадь 8 прямоугольных треугольников с катетом, равным половине стороны квадрата, и гипотенузой-радиусом (по теореме Пифагора).

Comment: Спасибо за ответ)